# a concise form for concatenating a string, conditioned on some condition in python

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

Many times I find myself writing code in the following form:

```
conditional_str = ''
if condition:
    conditional_str = ' blah blah'

output = 'my constant string' + conditional_str
```

I find it a bit cumbersome, and looking for a concise way of doing it.
One way is to put this piece of code to a function.

```
output = conditional_str_concat(const_str, condition, conditional_str )
```

But I was wondering if there are better pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only other clean solution would be a conditional expression:

```
# Concatenate an empty string if "not condition"
output = 'my constant string' + (' blah blah' if condition else '')
```

This is essentially what you had before, just inline. Whether or not it's better is up for debate.

You could make it a function as you mentioned, but I don't think it should be the job of a function to conditionally call code for you based on a passed-in flag (`condition`). I think the caller should just handle `condition` themselves.